# Select multiple images and show them in a form

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gallery, multi-select

I'm using Xamarin.Forms to create an Android + iOS app. I'm still new to this but the internet is not helping in finding an answer for the problem I have.

I'm trying to create a form where one of the parts consists on an image selector.
The idea is:

- provide a button that opens the gallery
- the user selects as many images as he/she wants
- the images are showed on a table (table as generic concept, not necessary object). This table shall have 3 columns by whatever lines needed.

In order to achieve this I currently have two problems:

1. I'm using CrossMedia plugin to access the gallery, but this only allow me to retrieve one image. I haven't found a wait to support multi-selection. Responses I've seen on the internet are either platform specific or not supported anymore.
2. If I manage to get the list of selected images, how do I display it in a tabular form?

This is what I currently have:

**XAML**

*Inside a TableSection*

```
<ViewCell>
  <Grid x:Name="imageGrid" Margin="15" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Photos" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Text="Add" Clicked="Select_Photos" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" />

  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
<ImageCell x:Name="img_selected" Text="Bla" ImageSource="http://xamarin.com/images/index/ide-xamarin-studio.png" />
```

**CS**

```
async void Select_Photos(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
      if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
      {
        await DisplayAlert("Need Storage", "Gunna need that Storage", "OK");
      }

      var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
      status = results[Permission.Storage];
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
      await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
      if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
      {
        await DisplayAlert("no upload", "picking a photo is not supported", "ok");
        return;
      }

      var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
      if (file == null)
        return;

      img_selected.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(file.GetStream);
    }
    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
      await DisplayAlert("Storage Permission Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

What happens here is that I'm able to select one image and display it.
Now I need to find a way to take the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this in Xamarin forms with platform-specific implementations of an image service for iOS/Android. On iOS I'm using a library called ELCImagePicker to help. Apparently it's not supported anymore, but still working fine for me. Just directly referencing the dll from my iOS project, but I can't find where I downloaded the dll I'm using, but I've included a link to the source below.

My app uses [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection) to access the IImageService implementation. So my iOS and Android projects register their ImageService classes with the IOC on startup. 
Like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IImageService>(() => new ImageService());
```

You could also just have them provide their implementation directly to your xamarin forms code by passing a reference directly during startup, or some other way.

This is the interface I defined, which is in my Xamarin Forms project:

```
public interface IImageService
{
    Task<List<MediaFile>> PickImages(int maxImagesCount = 1);
    Task<MediaFile> TakePhoto();

    Stream GenerateThumbnail(MediaFile file);

    bool IsPickImagesSupported { get; }
    bool IsTakePhotoSupported { get; }
}
```

In a [Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects) project I've defined the parts of the image service that are not platform-specific:

```
public partial class ImageService : IImageService
{
    public bool IsPickImagesSupported => CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported;

    public bool IsTakePhotoSupported => CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported;

    public Task<MediaFile> TakePhoto() => CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
             CompressionQuality = 92
        });
}
```

The iOS implementation inside the iOS project using [ECLImagePicker](https://github.com/bjdodson/XamarinSharpPlus/blob/master/iOS/ELCImagePicker/ELCImagePickerViewController.cs) to support multiple image picking:

```
public partial class ImageService : IImageService
{
    public ImageService()
    {
        ELCImagePickerViewController.OverlayImage = UIImage.FromFile("BlueCheck.png");
    }

    public Stream GenerateThumbnail(MediaFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var image = UIImage.FromFile(file.Path))
            {
                if (image is null)
                    return null;
                var thumb = image.ResizeImageWithAspectRatio(150, 150);

                return thumb.AsJPEG(.92f).AsStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.LogError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<MediaFile>> PickImages(int maxImagesCount = 1)
    {
        var images = new List<MediaFile>();
        try
        {
            if (maxImagesCount == 1)
            {
                var image = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions { CompressionQuality = 92 });
                if (image != null) images.Add(image);
            }
            else
            {
                var picker = ELCImagePickerViewController.Create(maxImagesCount);

                try
                {
                    var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
                    while (topController.PresentedViewController != null)
                    {
                        topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
                    }
                    topController.PresentViewController(picker, true, null);

                    var items = await picker.Completion;

                    if (items != null && items.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            images.Add(new MediaFile(
                                path: GetPathToImage(item.Image, item.Name),
                                streamGetter: () => item.Image.AsJPEG(0.92f).AsStream()
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
                finally
                {
                    picker.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        //dismiss the picker
                        picker.DismissViewController(true, null);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.LogError(ex);
        }

        return images;
    }

    public static string GetPathToImage(UIImage image, string name)
    {
        var tempDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string jpgFilename = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, name); 

        var imgData = image.AsJPEG(.92f);
        NSError err = null;
        if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
        {
            return jpgFilename;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

And the Android version:

```
public partial class ImageService : IImageService
{
    public const int IMAGES_SELECTED = 200;

    readonly TimeSpan TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    readonly Activity sourceActivity;

    List<MediaFile> pickedImages = null;
    bool waitingForimages = false;

    public ImageService(Activity sourceActivity)
    {
        this.sourceActivity = sourceActivity;
    }

    public System.IO.Stream GenerateThumbnail(MediaFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            var imagePath = file.Path;

            var originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath);
            double desiredWidth = 150;
            double desiredHeight = originalImage.Height * (desiredWidth / originalImage.Width);
            var rotation = GetRotation(imagePath);
            Bitmap finalImage = originalImage;

            if (rotation != 0)
            {
                var matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.PostRotate(rotation);
                finalImage = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, matrix, true);
                originalImage.Recycle();
                originalImage.Dispose();
            }

            finalImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(finalImage, Convert.ToInt32(desiredWidth), Convert.ToInt32(desiredHeight), true);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            finalImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 92, ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            finalImage.Recycle();
            finalImage.Dispose();
            // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
            GC.Collect();

            return ms;
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { return null;}
    }



    public async Task<List<MediaFile>> PickImages(int maxImagesCount = 1)
    {
        if (maxImagesCount > 1)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(sourceActivity.BaseContext, $"Select a maximum of {maxImagesCount} images", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            var imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
            imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
            imageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
            imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            pickedImages = null;
            sourceActivity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photos"), IMAGES_SELECTED);

            Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for images...");

            waitingForimages = true;
            while (waitingForimages && (DateTime.Now - startTime) < TIMEOUT)
            {await Task.Delay(250);}

            Debug.WriteLine("Wait for images finished.");

            waitingForimages = false;
            return pickedImages;
        }
        else
        {
            var images = new List<MediaFile>();

            var image = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions { CompressionQuality = 92 });
            if (image != null) images.Add(image);

            return images;
        }
    }

    public async Task OnPickImagesResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data, ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        if (requestCode != IMAGES_SELECTED) throw new ArgumentException("invalid request code for images service:" + requestCode); 
        if (resultCode != Result.Ok)
        {//Canceled or failed
            pickedImages = null;
            waitingForimages = false;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                var images = new List<MediaFile>();
                ClipData clipData = data.ClipData;
                if (clipData != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
                    {
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
                        Android.Net.Uri uri = item.Uri;
                        var path = await GetFileForUriAsync(sourceActivity, uri);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                        {
                            var image = await ImageToMediaFile(path);
                            images.Add(image);
                        }
                        else throw new Exception($"Image import {i+1} of {clipData.ItemCount} failed", new Exception(uri.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                    var path = await GetFileForUriAsync(sourceActivity, uri);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                    {
                        var image = await ImageToMediaFile(path);
                        images.Add(image);
                    }
                    else throw new Exception("Image import failed");
                }

                pickedImages = images;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.LogError(ex);
            Toast.MakeText(sourceActivity, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        waitingForimages = false;
    }

    static async Task<MediaFile> ImageToMediaFile(string imagePath)
    {
        MediaFile imageFile = null;

        var originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath);
        var rotation = GetRotation(imagePath);
        Bitmap finalImage = originalImage;

        if (rotation != 0)
        {
            var matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.PostRotate(rotation);
            finalImage = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, matrix, true);
            originalImage.Recycle();
            originalImage.Dispose();
        }

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await finalImage.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 92, ms);
        imageFile = new MediaFile(imagePath, () =>
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return ms;
        });

        finalImage.Recycle();
        finalImage.Dispose();
        // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
        GC.Collect();

        return imageFile;
    }

    static int GetRotation(string filePath)
    {
        using (var ei = new ExifInterface(filePath))
        {
            var orientation = (Android.Media.Orientation)ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Normal);

            switch (orientation)
            {
                case Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate90:
                    return 90;
                case Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate180:
                    return 180;
                case Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate270:
                    return 270;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the file for URI, including making a local temp copy. 
    /// Imported from media picker plugin source. 
    /// https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Android/MediaPickerActivity.cs
    /// </summary>
    internal static Task<string> GetFileForUriAsync(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, bool isPhoto = true, bool saveToAlbum = false)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        if (uri.Scheme == "file")
            tcs.SetResult(new System.Uri(uri.ToString()).LocalPath);
        else if (uri.Scheme == "content")
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ICursor cursor = null;
                try
                {
                    string[] proj = null;
                    if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 22)
                        proj = new[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data };

                    cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor is null || !cursor.MoveToNext())
                        tcs.SetResult(null);
                    else
                    {
                        var column = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data);
                        string contentPath = null;

                        if (column != -1)
                            contentPath = cursor.GetString(column);



                        // If they don't follow the "rules", try to copy the file locally
                        if (contentPath is null || !contentPath.StartsWith("file", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            string fileName = null;
                            try
                            {
                                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(contentPath);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get file path name, using new unique " + ex);
                            }


                            var outputPath = GetOutputMediaFile(context, "temp", fileName, isPhoto, false);

                            try
                            {
                                using (var input = context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
                                using (var output = File.Create(outputPath.Path))
                                    input.CopyTo(output);

                                contentPath = outputPath.Path;
                            }
                            catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException fnfEx)
                            {
                                // If there's no data associated with the uri, we don't know
                                // how to open this. contentPath will be null which will trigger
                                // MediaFileNotFoundException.
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to save picked file from disk " + fnfEx);
                            }
                        }

                        tcs.SetResult(contentPath);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cursor != null)
                    {
                        cursor.Close();
                        cursor.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        else
            tcs.SetResult(null);

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Uri GetOutputMediaFile(Context context, string subdir, string name, bool isPhoto, bool saveToAlbum)
    {
        subdir = subdir ?? string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (isPhoto)
                name = "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg";
            else
                name = "VID_" + timestamp + ".mp4";
        }

        var mediaType = (isPhoto) ? Environment.DirectoryPictures : Environment.DirectoryMovies;
        var directory = saveToAlbum ? Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mediaType) : context.GetExternalFilesDir(mediaType);
        using (var mediaStorageDir = new Java.IO.File(directory, subdir))
        {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs())
                    throw new IOException("Couldn't create directory, have you added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?");

                if (!saveToAlbum)
                {
                    // Ensure this media doesn't show up in gallery apps
                    using (var nomedia = new Java.IO.File(mediaStorageDir, ".nomedia"))
                        nomedia.CreateNewFile();
                }
            }

            return Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(GetUniquePath(mediaStorageDir.Path, name, isPhoto)));
        }
    }

    private static string GetUniquePath(string folder, string name, bool isPhoto)
    {
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(name);
        if (ext == string.Empty)
            ext = ((isPhoto) ? ".jpg" : ".mp4");

        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);

        var nname = name + ext;
        var i = 1;
        while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(folder, nname)))
            nname = name + "_" + (i++) + ext;

        return Path.Combine(folder, nname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ben.
Unfortunately, as I said, I'm still new to Xamarin so I'm a bit lost on how to get this going:
 - What is the Preserve attribute?
 - Where does the IImageService comes from?
 - How to call this from the xaml?
 - How does the compiler knows which piece of code to call?

Comment: Hi Nahoot, I've updated my answer will the interface and full implementations. If you're not sure how to setup a shared project, I've included a link that should help. I've removed the preserve attribute to avoid confusion - it's used to ensure the code is not removed by the linker, which is a separate topic you'll want to learn about when/if you are preparing to release an app to the store. You don't call this from xaml, you would call the image service from code-behind or a command in your view model (if using mvvm).